# The \label and \ref are not working for me even after compiling twice

Tags: cross-referencing

Here is my simple document

```
\textbf{Theorem 3. }
\it{Let $M_R$ be a $C3$-module. If $M=X\s Y$ and $f:X\to Y$ is a homomorphism with 
$\ker f \ds X$, then $\im f \ds Y$.}\label{theorem3}


An immediate consequence of Theorem \ref{theorem3} is the following.
```

I try to reference the theorem but when I insert `\ref` and compile for the first time two question marks appear, and when I compile for the second time the two question marks disappear and no number appear.

Where is the fault?. Is there a proper way to reference a text like so?

Comment: there is not theorem to reference. You simply write the word  "Theorem 3" in bold. Use a proper theorem environment.

Comment: Is there a way to reference a text like the one written in the demo above ?

Comment: Do you have sequential theorems (1, 2, 3, ...) in your document? Or do you arbitrarily put theorems in your document (3, 7, 12, ...)?

Comment: arbitrary numbering.

Comment: Usually \label refers to the previous \refstepcounter, but with arbitrary numbering that would be difficult.

Comment: in addition to this not being an environment that can be referenced.  do not use \it in latex. it is not defined by default and in classes where it is defined the syntax is {\it ABC}  not \it{ABC}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the standard interface for theorems instead of an error prone manual formatting for each of them.

I define the `mthm` (**m**anual **th**eore**m**) environment in terms of a standard theorem-like one (called `mthminner`) that sets up a counter which we can use by redefining the associated representation `\themthminner` as we prefer. The optional argument can be used to set the header (default “Theorem”) to “Corollary”, “Lemma” or whatever.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{mthminner}{\mthminnername}
\newcommand{\mthminnername}{}
\newenvironment{mthm}[2][Theorem]
 {%
  \renewcommand\themthminner{#2}%
  \renewcommand{\mthminnername}{#1}%
  \begin{mthminner}%
 }
 {\end{mthminner}}

\newcommand{\s}{\oplus}
\newcommand{\ds}{\leq^{\oplus}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{im}

\begin{document}

\begin{mthm}{3}\label{theorem3}
Let $M_R$ be a $C3$-module. If $M=X\s Y$ and $f:X\to Y$ is a homomorphism with 
$\ker f \ds X$, then $\im f \ds Y$.
\end{mthm}

An immediate consequence of Theorem \ref{theorem3} is the following corollary.

\begin{mthm}[Corollary]{3.1}\label{corollary3.1}
Corollaries are easy.
\end{mthm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different approach for multiple statement types.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newcounter{mthm}
\newtheorem{mthmitalic}[mthm]{\mthmname}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{mthmroman}[mthm]{\mthmname}
\newcommand{\mthmname}{}

\newcommand{\varnewtheorem}[3]{%
  \newenvironment{#1}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\mthmname}{#2}%
    \renewcommand{\themthm}{##1}%
    \csname mthm#3\endcsname
  }{\csname endmthm#3\endcsname}%
}

\varnewtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}{italic}
\varnewtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}{italic}
\varnewtheorem{definition}{Definition}{roman}
\varnewtheorem{example}{Example}{roman}

\newcommand{\s}{\oplus}
\newcommand{\ds}{\leq^{\oplus}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{im}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}{A}
This is a definition of $X\ds Y$.
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}{3}\label{theorem3}
Let $M_R$ be a $C3$-module. If $M=X\s Y$ and $f:X\to Y$ is a homomorphism with 
$\ker f \ds X$, then $\im f \ds Y$.
\end{theorem}

An immediate consequence of Theorem \ref{theorem3} is the following corollary.

\begin{corollary}{3.1}\label{corollary3.1}
Corollaries are easy.
\end{corollary}

And we can even give examples.

\begin{example}{42}
This is an example related to Corollary~\ref{corollary3.1}
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for forgetting to reveal that. `\it` is a declaration made by me that italicizes the font. It's an abbreviation for `\textit{}`, and `\s` is an abbreviation for `\oplus`, and `\ds` is an abbreviation for `\leq^{\oplus}` .

Comment: But it another problem will be still there. How to define the lemmas and corollaries ?

Comment: @HusseinEid I modified the code to allow for different headers.

Comment: This is so great. One more question please: Is it possible to include definitions, examples, remarks such that they are NOT italic (as usual)?

Comment: @HusseinEid Look at the edit.

Comment: Infinite thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

`\@currentlabel` needs to be updated for your approach to work. The following example defines the `arbitrarytheorem` environment that takes a single argument (the number), and updated `\@currentlabel` accordingly. This allows you to use `\label`-`\ref` as intended.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{arbitrarytheorem}[1]{%
  \par
  \addvspace{.25\baselineskip}% Space above (arbitrary) theorem
  \noindent\textbf{Theorem~#1.}% Theorem heading
  \edef\@currentlabel{#1}% Store current label
  \itshape% Default shape used within theorem
  \ignorespaces
}{%
  \par
  \addvspace{.25\baselineskip}% Space below (arbitrary) theorem
}

\begin{document}

\begin{arbitrarytheorem}{3}
Let $M_R$ be a $C3$-module. If $M = X \setminus Y$ and $f : X \to Y$ is a homomorphism with $\int f \mathrm{d}s X$, then $\int f \mathrm{d}s Y$.
\label{theorem3}
\end{arbitrarytheorem}

An immediate consequence of Theorem~\ref{theorem3} is the following. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you have `\label` at the beginning, it will produce unwanted spaces; if you have it at the end it will produce unwanted spaces.

Comment: I already tried this solution but the problem is that this environment produces unwanted spaced before and after the theorem. @egreg

Comment: @HusseinEid Why are you commenting here and not to my answer? And why wouldn't you want some vertical space around the statement?